# How to insert elements in a c++ set until enter is pressed?

Tags: c++, input, set

For example: insert 1 5 88 99 7 in a set if 1,5,88,99,7 is given as an input and then pressed Enter.
My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
set <char> num;
set <char> ::iterator i;
int main()
{
 int a;
 while(a=getchar())
 {

    if(a!='\n')
    {
        if(a!=',')
            num.insert(a);
    }
    else
        break;
}
for(i=num.begin(); i!=num.end(); i++)
    cout<<*i<<endl;
}
```

The output I'm getting:
1
5
7
8
9

Comment: Obligitory: [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. It's not a standard header.

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Edited my question @user463035818

Comment: You're reading 1 char at a time. That gives you 1, 5, 8, 8, 9, 9, and 7

Comment: `[help-me]` What output did you expect?

Comment: Why are you using a `set`?

Comment: @Arkadiy I was expecting 1 5 7 88 99. But my method for taking input was wrong.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to reflect the actual problem

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm trying to solve a Codeforces problem. It requires the use of set.

Comment: And you should remove the Wave Motion Cannon of code destruction that is `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` You can get away with it for trivial code, but zowie! Including the entire standard library (via a non-standard header) and then tossing the entire standard library into the global namespace leaves you with an identifier minefield to contend with as your programs grow in size and complexity.

Comment: why do you use set<char> instead of set<int> if you are (I think) trying to read integers?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   // cin >> s;
   string s = "5,2,3,4,1",t = "";
   stringstream ss(s);
   set<int> s_;
   while( getline(ss,t,',') )
       s_.insert(stoi(t));
   for(auto i : s_)
       cout << i << " ";
}
```

Outputs: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: The concept is good, but the main sin of this answer, and maybe the reason for the downvote, is it makes no attempt to explain what you did and why. This is a code-only answer and sometimes they work, but most of the time they just lead to some poor, confused asker becoming a [Cargo Cult Programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) This answer is easily salvaged by adding even a brief explanation of the problem, why it's a problem, and how your code solves the problem..

Comment: `cout << "1 2 3 4 5"` also outputs 1 2 3 4 5. <- this answer is just as useful.. Code without explanation is useless for questions like these.

Comment: I omitted  string s = "5,2,3,4,1" and took various inputs. It works. But I don't understand how getline(ss,t,',') is working.

Comment: @user2143094 [`std::getline` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). [`std::stringstream` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). Together they make for one of the most useful tools in the C++ string parsing arsenal. For example, [take a look at option 2 in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301). `getline` reads until it finds a delimiter, ',' in this case and places what it found into the given `string`. Typically you leave out the delimiter and `getline` assumes end of line.

Comment: And a bit of snark: I recommend against selecting an answer as THE answer if you do not understand the answer. If you don't know what was done and how, how can you be sure the answer actually solves the problem? This one does, but it needs more explanation for you to be able to apply it to your problem correctly.

Answer (score -2):

1) To match your modified question (reading integers of any length) char by char, means you need to look at each and see if it is a digit.  If it is, you need to keep a running value based on each additional digit you receive.

2) Your set needs to be of int, not char if you're going to save the actual integer values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

set <int> num;
set <int> ::iterator i;
int main()
{
  int a;
  int full_num=0;
  while(a=getchar())
  {
     if (isdigit(a)) 
     {
       full_num = full_num*10 + (a - '0');
     } 
       else if (a==',' || a=='\n') 
     {
       num.insert(full_num);
       full_num = 0;
       if (a=='\n') break;
     }
   }
   for(i=num.begin(); i!=num.end(); i++)
       cout<<*i<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: the original question had single digit examples, but has been edited to show they want any integers now, so yes, this doesn't work for that case

Comment: edited answer and included code to match the modified question.

Comment: full_num = full_num*10 + (a - '0'); //full_num doesn't have an initial value. @J.Fay

Comment: thanks - fixed it to initialize to 0 the first time through.